# When is validity definable in $L_\alpha$?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, descriptive-set-theory

*Below, $\alpha$ is a countable p.r.-closed ordinal $>\omega$.*

---

Let $\mathcal{L}_\alpha=\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}\cap L_\alpha$ (note that this is not the same as $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}\cap L_\alpha$ since elements of the latter are explicitly countable). By the Barwise completeness theorem if $\alpha$ is admissible or a limit of admissibles the set of $\mathcal{L}_\alpha$-validities is definable in $L_\alpha$ - indeed, it's $\Sigma_1$ over $L_\alpha$ - the point being that we have a good notion of *proof*.

However, if $\alpha$ is neither admissible nor a limit of admissible this argument breaks down. For *some* such $\alpha$ the result still holds, e.g. if $L_\theta$ is interpretable in $L_\alpha$ where $\theta$ is the next admissible above $\alpha$ *(and in particular whenever the supremum of the $\alpha$-recursive ordinals is admissible)*, but that seems rather rare *(e.g. club-many countable ordinals are [non-Gandy](https://mathoverflow.net/a/277345/8133))*.

My question is:

> For which $\alpha$ is $\mathcal{L}_\alpha$-validity definable in $L_\alpha$?

*(I'd also be interested in the finer-grained question of $\Sigma_1$-definability; for what it's worth, I'm not sure which is harder.)* "Obviously" this should fail for most $\alpha$ ... but at present I don't even have an example of a *single* $\alpha$ for which it fails!

---

Closely related is the following question:

> Supposing $\varphi\in\mathcal{L}_\alpha$ is a validity, how high up in the $L$-hierarchy do I have to look to find a proof of $\varphi$?

I suspect the answer to this question is *not* in general "unboundedly high below the next admissible."

Comment: Note that unlike Barwise completeness, Barwise *compactness* does **not** apply to inadmissible limits of admissibles. For example, work in $\theta=\sup_{n\in\omega}\omega_n^{CK}$, for $i\in\omega$ let $\varphi_i$ be the sentence saying that $L_{\omega_i^{CK}}$ is an initial segment of the universe, and let $\psi$ be the sentence "$\omega$ is standard and there are only finitely many admissible ordinals." Then $\{\varphi_i:i\in\omega\}\cup\{\psi\}$ is $\mathcal{L}_\theta$-finitely satisfiable but clearly unsatisfiable.